# Track iOS Device Motion Updates in Background for more than 10 minutes

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, background-task, devicemotion

I have an app which checks the gravity of the iPhone every second in the background. When I run this code while connected to Xcode, the program runs for more than 30 minutes in the background. However, when it is not connected to Xcode, it stop running before 10 minutes are over in the background. I use location updates and motion updates:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        NSLog(@"End Background Tasks");
    }];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8) {
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9) {
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
}
```

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19891765/341994

Answer (score 0):

Check that the target has Background Modes enabled under Capabilities, and make sure the Location updates mode is set.

Comment: I did that and both are set.